# How to estimate error of regression parameters from data with errors

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

I'm a physics student and in school we often measure some data (like voltage and current) and then use regression to determine an unknown quantity (ie. resistance in this case). My problem is that I know the standard errors of all measured quantities (and assume they are independent and normally distributed) but don't know how to determine the standard error of the regression's parameters from that.

To put it more rigorously, let's say we have a set of points $[x_i, y_i]$ with known standard errors $[\sigma_{x_i}, \sigma_{y_i}]$ and a function $f(a_1, \dots a_n, x)$, generally not linear in parameters $a_j$. We know that the values of $[x_i, y_i]$ were obtained from $[X_i, Y_i = f(A_1, \dots A_n, X_i)]$ where $X_i, Y_i, A_j$ are the true values that were just imprecisely measured. Via the [weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares) regression we find the values of $a_j$ which are the "measurements" of $A_j$. How can one estimate the standard error of such measurement?

Most software I used does compute some sort of standard errors for parameters, but those never account for the standard error of data, only the "fluctuations" of the values.